# Replicating between two databases that are firewalled, using a machine in the middle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016, database-replication

I have 2 SQL servers: one running SQL Server 2008, the other SQL Server 2016. These two databases cannot, and will not be able to talk to each other directly due to complex firewalling rules. The machines in question do not support a large user group, or host large amounts of data. 5 active users for a few minutes each at most on a busy day. 60mb of data in the target DB.

I have a Windows 7 machine in the middle that is capable of talking to both as it possesses the necessary permissions to reach both.

I'm trying to schedule a job to copy the DB from SQL Server 2008 to SQL server 2016 every hour. This job fails as it appears that the scheduled job causes SQL server 2016 to attempt to connect directly to SQL server 2008 (great! but not in this case.). This fails due to aforementioned firewalling with an error message "unable to connect to [target machine]".

**Is there a way that I can use the third windows machine that can connect to both via SQL Management Studio to broker the transaction.** Opening up a proxy, for example, isn't possible. The current method is to use this third machine to create a DB extract from SQL Server 2008 and then import it to SQL Server 2016. I know this isn't the recommended approach - but it's part of a bigger plan and will save me bulk time for now.

I've not used SSIS before, but perhaps there is a way forward here?
Any third party software (FOSS?) that might help (not that I've found)?
Open to ideas.

Comment: Can you share the detail (script) of your scheduled job?